# Search for square inside array of points

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I'm setting up a computer-vision application but I'm stuck with a control that I have to apply to an array of coordinates. I would like to retrieve **all** the possible square from an array of coordinates.

```
    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image, 20, 0.01, 15)
    corners = np.int0(corners)
    print("Points")
    for corner in corners:
        x, y = corner.ravel()
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    print(corners)
    corners = corners.tolist()
    corners = flatten(corners)
```

This is only a part of the array of points that I have to use to retrieve all the square inside my image:

```
[[10,50],[420,188],[177,425],[225,425],[176,220],[225,221],[10,170],[21,50],[21,170]]
```

Comment: Square means two number are same in array like [225,225]?

Comment: I would like to iterate all the points to find which of them for a square. I've posted only a part of the array, but in the final result, I want to retrieve all of them(more than one). For example, 4 points of the array form a square(i save the coordinates of those points) and continue to check if there are other combinations that can form a square and so on until all the combination of point are tried by the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

One ugly way to do this would be to iterate over all the combinations of 4 points and to check that they define a square.

Here a function to check the square status :

```
def is_square_func(a, b, c, d):
    is_square = a[0] == b[0]
    is_square = (is_square and c[0] == d[0])
    is_square = (is_square and a[1] == c[1])
    is_square = (is_square and b[1] == d[1])

    # Condition to find a square only once
    is_square = (is_square and a[0] > c[0])
    is_square = (is_square and c[1] > d[1])

    return is_square
```

And here the function to apply on your coordinates list :

```
def find_squares(point_array):
    n = len(point_array)
    squares = []
    for i in range(n):
         for j in range(n):
                 if i == j:
                         continue
                 for k in range(n):
                         if i == k or j == k:
                                 continue
                         for l in range(n):
                                 if i == l or j == l or k == l:
                                         continue
                                 if is_square_func(point_array[i], point_array[j], point_array[k], point_array[l]):
                                         print("New square")
                                         print(point_array[i])
                                         print(point_array[j])
                                         print(point_array[k])
                                         print(point_array[l])
                                         squares += [point_array[i], point_array[j], point_array[k], point_array[l]]
    return squares
```